# Remove Item from Dropdown Box if Selected in Another Dropdown Box in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a userform in Powerpoint that has 5 pages on it (tabs across the top, each one you click takes you to a new page within the same userform). I have one combobox dropdown on each page. They are all populated from the same location (a module in the vba code). Here is the code where the list of dropdown options are stored:

```
Sub HazardTypeSevere()

'List of items to include in the Severe dropdown.

Dim strlist As String
     'Put them in an Array declared as Public
     strlist = "Damaging Winds,Large Hail,Tornadoes"
     rayNames = Split(strlist, ",")

End Sub
```

In my userform code, this is the code that populates the dropdown:

```
Private Sub HazardType2_DropButtonClick()
Call DropdownOptions.HazardTypeSevere

'List all the severe hazard type dropdown options in Hazard 2


'This is where I am trying to tell it to remove whatever is selected in the 
'HazardType1 dropdown from the HazardType2 dropdown.
If HazardType1 <> "" Then 'If anything is selected in the HazardType1 
'dropdown...
HazardType2.RemoveItem (HazardType1.Value) 'Remove the item that is 
'selected in HazardType1
End If

Dim L As Long

    If HazardType2.ListCount = 0 Then
        With HazardType2
        .Clear
        For L = 0 To UBound(rayNames)
            .AddItem rayNames(L)
        Next L
        .Value = rayNames(0)
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

When I run the code above I get the "Invalid Argument" error. The 'HazardType1.Value' does indeed show what is selected in the HazardType1 dropdown.

I'm not sure if this is possible without having a separate list of items written to call on to populate the dropdown. But that would not be possible since there are a lot of options in the dropdown boxes.

Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: I'm not fully clear what you are asking. Is it the case you want the list in DropDown2 to be Dependent on what (if anything) is selected in DropDown1 ? ... and similarly for the other 3 DropDowns. If yes, then your comment "would not be possible since there are a lot of options" can be solved and that might be the way forward ... more info would help

Comment: Hi. Yes. If something is selected in DropDown1 or DropDown2, etc., then whatever is selected there would not show up in any of the other dropdowns as possible options. That make sense?

Comment: Your question still stands unclear to me. Try to say in other words.

Comment: Ok, in all 5 dropdowns, there are initially the same options (1,2,3,4,5). If the user selects 1 in DropDown1, then that option will not appear in the other 4 DropDown options. If the user selects 5 in DropDown2, then that option will not appear in the other 4 dropdowns.

Comment: I've been trying this out, but your description means when all are selected none can then be changed, because each must exclude the choices already made for all the others - so using 5 dropdowns for 5 choices means there are 4 excluded values for each of the 5 dropdowns, so only 1 viable option for each (once initially selected). You need at least 6 options for 5 dropdowns to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 ComboBox1.List = Split(" ,1,2,3,4,5", ",")
 ComboBox2.List = Split(" ,1,2,3,4,5", ",")
 ComboBox3.List = Split(" ,1,2,3,4,5", ",")
 ComboBox4.List = Split(" ,1,2,3,4,5", ",")
 ComboBox5.List = Split(" ,1,2,3,4,5", ",")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
   ManageDropDowns (1)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
   ManageDropDowns (2)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
   ManageDropDowns (3)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()
   ManageDropDowns (4)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()
   ManageDropDowns (5)
End Sub

Sub ManageDropDowns(IDNum As Integer)
   '
   ' Presuming we have 5 Comboboxes
   ' This routine ensures there are initially 6 choices for each ComboBox - a blank empty choice and 5 values 1-5
   ' This will then ensure no 2 ComboBoxes can make the same choice from 1-5 (all can choose blank)
   '
   Dim UsedList As String, FullList As String, Left2Use As String
   Dim FullArray As Variant, UsedArray(1 To 5) As String

   UL1 = ""
   UL1 = UL1 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox2.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox2.Value) & ",")
   UL1 = UL1 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox3.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox3.Value) & ",")
   UL1 = UL1 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox4.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox4.Value) & ",")
   UL1 = UL1 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox5.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox5.Value) & ",")
   While Right(UL1, 1) = ","
      UL1 = Left(UL1, Len(UL1) - 1)
   Wend

   UL2 = ""
   UL2 = UL2 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox1.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox1.Value) & ",")
   UL2 = UL2 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox3.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox3.Value) & ",")
   UL2 = UL2 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox4.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox4.Value) & ",")
   UL2 = UL2 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox5.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox5.Value) & ",")

   UL3 = ""
   UL3 = UL3 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox2.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox2.Value) & ",")
   UL3 = UL3 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox1.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox1.Value) & ",")
   UL3 = UL3 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox4.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox4.Value) & ",")
   UL3 = UL3 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox5.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox5.Value) & ",")

   UL4 = ""
   UL4 = UL4 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox2.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox2.Value) & ",")
   UL4 = UL4 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox3.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox3.Value) & ",")
   UL4 = UL4 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox1.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox1.Value) & ",")
   UL4 = UL4 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox5.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox5.Value) & ",")

   UL5 = ""
   UL5 = UL5 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox2.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox2.Value) & ",")
   UL5 = UL5 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox3.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox3.Value) & ",")
   UL5 = UL5 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox4.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox4.Value) & ",")
   UL5 = UL5 & IIf(Trim(ComboBox1.Value) = "", "", "" & Trim(ComboBox1.Value) & ",")

   FullList = "1,2,3,4,5"
   FullArray = Split(FullList, ",")
   Left2Use = " ,"

   If IDNum <> 1 Then
      UsedList = UL1
      Left2Use = " "  ' Space
      For i = 0 To UBound(FullArray)
         iTxt = Trim("" & i + 1)
         If Not (InStr(1, UsedList, iTxt) > 0) Then
            ' Not Already Used - Add it to Left2Use
            Left2Use = Left2Use & "," & iTxt
         End If
      Next i
      ComboBox1.List = Split(Left2Use, ",")
   End If
   If IDNum <> 2 Then
      UsedList = UL2
      Left2Use = " "  ' Space
      For i = 0 To UBound(FullArray)
         iTxt = Trim("" & i + 1)
         If Not (InStr(1, UsedList, iTxt) > 0) Then
            ' Not Already Used - Add it to Left2Use
            Left2Use = Left2Use & "," & iTxt
         End If
      Next i
      ComboBox2.List = Split(Left2Use, ",")
   End If
   If IDNum <> 3 Then
      UsedList = UL3
      Left2Use = " "  ' Space
      For i = 0 To UBound(FullArray)
         iTxt = Trim("" & i + 1)
         If Not (InStr(1, UsedList, iTxt) > 0) Then
            ' Not Already Used - Add it to Left2Use
            Left2Use = Left2Use & "," & iTxt
         End If
      Next i
      ComboBox3.List = Split(Left2Use, ",")
   End If
   If IDNum <> 4 Then
      UsedList = UL4
      Left2Use = " "  ' Space
      For i = 0 To UBound(FullArray)
         iTxt = Trim("" & i + 1)
         If Not (InStr(1, UsedList, iTxt) > 0) Then
            ' Not Already Used - Add it to Left2Use
            Left2Use = Left2Use & "," & iTxt
         End If
      Next i
      ComboBox4.List = Split(Left2Use, ",")
   End If
   If IDNum <> 5 Then
      UsedList = UL5
      Left2Use = " "  ' Space
      For i = 0 To UBound(FullArray)
         iTxt = Trim("" & i + 1)
         If Not (InStr(1, UsedList, iTxt) > 0) Then
            ' Not Already Used - Add it to Left2Use
            Left2Use = Left2Use & "," & iTxt
         End If
      Next i
      ComboBox5.List = Split(Left2Use, ",")
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Dang. That's perfect! Exactly what I needed. Just modified it to fit my needs and it works perfectly. Thanks so much!